# How to Convert a char to a local variable of Type Letter Called Guessed.?

Tags: java

1. Switch back to the Phrase class.  Add a new method guessLetter that returns a boolean 
   and takes a char as an argument.  This will be used to see if a player guesses a letter 
   correctly.  This method should:
   ● Convert the char to a local variable of type Letter called guessed
   ● Return true if guessed is in letters, otherwise return false

> ```
> public class Phrase {
>   private String phrase;
>
>   public Phrase(String phrase) {
>       phrase = phrase.toUpperCase();
>       for(char c : phrase.toCharArray()) {
>           letters.add(new Letter(c));
>       }
>   }
>
>   public String getPhrase() {
>       return phrase;
>   }
>
>   // public String phrase;
>   ArrayList<Letter> letters = new ArrayList<Letter>();
>
>   public ArrayList<Letter> getLetters() {
>       return letters;
>   }
>
>
> public boolean guessLetter(char c) {
>       char c = new char(Letter);
>       c = guessed;
>
>       return false;
>   }
>
> }
> ```

Thanks.  I can't figure this one out.

```
package edu.htc.java1.phrasegame.model;

public class Letter {
private char letter;

private boolean isHidden;

public int getLetter() {
    return letter;
}
public boolean isHidden() {
    return isHidden;
}

public void unhide() {
    isHidden = false;

}
public Letter(char letter) {
    this.letter = letter;
    if (String.valueOf(letter).matches("[A-Z]")) {
        isHidden = true;
    }
}

}
```

Comment: can we also have which school you are from and which professor asked the question? It is necessary to solve this question.

Comment: Thats irrelevant.  I don't want it done for me, I want an understanding of how to properly call it.  I can tell you i'm not finding any hints on google, nor my HeadFirst Java Book.

Comment: ok I will do this seriously, sorry about previous comment. Can you please provide me class letter too please? This is not something you can find on google, so I will try to help you myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`char c = new char(Letter);` should probably be `Letter guessedLetter = new Letter(c);`

I'm not sure what `c = guessed;` is supposed to be doing.

Then you'll need to see if `guessedLetter` is in `letters`. How you go about that depends on the implementation of `Letter`.

EDIT: Now that I see the `Letter` implementation, the correct solution is to override `equals()`in `Letter`, probably comparing `letter`. You can get away without implementing `hashCode()` in this exercise, but you really should override it too. Then your `guessLetter()` method can be:

```
public boolean guessLetter(char c) {
  return letters.contains(new Letter(c));
}
```

Or to meet the constraints in the problem:

```
public boolean guessLetter(char c) {
    Letter guessed = new Letter(c);
    return letters.contains(guessed);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My current assumption is this

```
public boolean guessLetter(char c)
{
    // convert received character to letter
    Letter letter = new Letter(c);

    // loop through your list of letters
    for(Letter l : letters)
    {
        // if list of letters contains same letter as the one you received then return true
        if(l.getLetter() == letter.getLetter())
            return true;
    }

    // we did not find the letter, so we return false
    return false;
}
```

Please do make sure that you read this code and understand it. No one is going to cry if you fail the class because you chose to copy paste the answer.

Comment: `if(l.getLetter() == letter.getLetter())` is a violation of "tell, don't ask". See http://martinfowler.com/bliki/TellDontAsk.html for more info.

Comment: My instructor encourages StackOverflow use.    But I understand your point and I appreciate the help.  StackOverflow is usually a last resort for me.

Comment: @user3381466 no problem. Sorry for rude comment previously. You do seem genuinely interested. You can't believe how many people expect just the answer usually, so I was unjustly hostile. Sorry :( Well good luck to you, and if you have any further questions, then do ask and we will help :)

Comment: @MikeB I agree with you, but in this case you are not asked to modify Letter class, therefore I chose to use what is provided rather than write equals method or such for Letter class.

Comment: So is this way proper?

Comment: @user3381466 for a school assignment it is absolutely proper (given that it works and does what it needs). For porfesional field not, but you needn't concern yourself with that. Just make sure that the value hidden has nothing to do with the letter, or it can be weird. But I like Mike's answer more. Just test aand see which one works best to your needs.